# Java Regex for lastname, firstname in java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regex and I want to look for **lastname, firstname**

I have written the following as regex but it is always failing. I don't care if lastname contains digits or anything but all I need to check is that lastname and firstname are separated by a space and a comma. I can do it manually but I want to use regex to do this.

```
^[\\w][\\w\\,\\s\\w]$
```

Comment: Have you written some test cases?

Comment: Are you looking for a regex to validate `string, string`?

Comment: @MRSmith42 yes it does not return true for Smith, Mark

Comment: Try your RegExps with one of the many online Regexp-tools to make your RegExp fit to your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex pattern:

```
^(\S)+, (\S)+$
```

Comment: Thank you Barry. Can you let me know what was I doing wrong earlier ?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] lastNameFirstName = fullName.split("\\s+,\\s+");
```

Index 0 will be your last name, while index 1 will be your first name.

Comment: Thank you Buhake, however I am just looking for the match